# Identity Server 4 AddInMemoryIdentityResources

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I was wondering if somebody can explain to me what `AddInMemoryIdentityResources` is used for when registering identity server during startup. From the examples they have shown it looks like this (note the code between comments):

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
.AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
.AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
//********************
.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
//********************
.AddInMemoryApiResources(configurationManager.GetApiResources())
.AddInMemoryClients(configurationManager.GetClients())
.AddAspNetIdentity<User>();
```

Then the config file is something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
{
    return new List<IdentityResource>
    {
        new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
        new IdentityResources.Profile(),
    };
}
```

Now, I thought that when you declare a client you define the scopes which basically say you are allowed to pass username, id, etc... However, then what is the point of this statement `.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())` as it seems to do the same thing but yet its global as it doesn't tie to any client?

Comment: Had similar confusion concerning production viability: _This style of configuration might also be appropriate for production scenarios if the configuration rarely changes_ @ [In-Memory configuration stores](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/startup.html#in-memory-configuration-stores)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AddInMemoryIdentityResources is basically defining the global list of available identity scopes. I.e. the master list which clients can then reference.

Comment: So does that mean I don't need it if I define scopes on clients? Or I always need this value defined?

Comment: The clients reference these by their scope names - so yes.

Comment: Sorry, your answer is a bit confusing for me. Are you saying that `AddInMemoryIdentityResources` is a whitelist of available scopes and then each client builds their own list of scopes to use, but that list has to be approved against the global list?

Comment: @Bojan that's exactly it, yes. There's a separate list for API resources and scopes too.